# Division in double variable returning always zero

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to perform division and multiplication between two values and then save them in a double variable.

Multiplication is working fine but division always returning zero ?

Why is it so ?

Here is my Code :

```
double max_load =(Convert.ToDouble(ddl_gene_desc.SelectedValue)*0.8)*(80/100);
```

I checked it using the breakpoint that multiplication is fine but (80/100) returning 0.

Can any one please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `80/100` (both integers) is always 0.

Change it to `80.0/100.0`

Comment: thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing two integer values, in this case "80/100" will return 0 because both values are integers and integers do not store a result. Try "80.0/100" to force floating point division.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll give you a vote :) –

Answer (score 1):

80 is int, so is 100 - hence integer division. Append 'F' to one of them to make it a float. Or double..

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll give you a vote :)